# Effect of hyperparameters: the hidden size, layers, MLP size number of heads on Transformer

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch, transformer

Is there any paper that explains the effect of hyperparameters:

- hidden size
- Number of layers
- MLP size
- number of heads

on Transformer performance. I found some explanation on the web but I need papers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific effect depends on the task you are using the task for which you are using the model. [The original Transformer article ("Attention is all you need")](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) includes a table with the effects of the different hyperparameter values on machine translation:

[image]